# Есть ли у библиотеки tksvg возможность прочитать svg напрямую из кода, а не из файла?

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть ли у библиотеки tksvg возможность прочитать svg напрямую из кода, а не из файла?
Если да, то как?

Нашел пример в PyQt5, есть ли что-то подобное в tksvg или tkinter?

```
def iconFromBase64(base_64):
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
    pixmap.loadFromData(QtCore.QByteArray.fromBase64(base_64), "SVG")
    icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)
    return icon
...
self.svg_str = """
    <svg width="210pt" height="210pt" viewBox="0 0 210 210">....</svg>
"""
svg_base64_str = b64encode(self.svg_str.encode('utf-8'))      
self.icon = iconFromBase64(svg_base64_str)
self.pb.setIcon(self.icon)
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У `PhotoImage()` есть аргумент `data`, через который передаются данные для создания картинки. Для бинарных форматов это base64-encoded содержимое файлов.  А для SVG - это содержимое самого файла (ибо оно и так текст).

```
from tkinter import *
import tksvg

svg="""
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="617" height="316">
<defs>
    <radialGradient id="g" cx="549.29" cy="159.12" r="127" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(.65 -1.52 1.4 .601129 -26.35 869.29)">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f00" stop-opacity=".27"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#f00"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient id="h" cx="492.86" cy="379.51" r="184.96" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(.945 .042 -0.043 .988 43.598 -15.991)">
        <stop offset=".5"/>
        <stop offset=".75"/>
        <stop offset=".88" stop-opacity=".72"/>
        <stop offset=".94" stop-opacity=".51"/>
        <stop offset=".97" stop-opacity=".33"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient id="k" cx="449.13" cy="345.23" r="184.96" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1.06 0 0 1 -30.44 2)">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fa4"/>
        <stop offset=".5" stop-color="#c3791f"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#935000"/>
    </radialGradient>
</defs>
<g fill-opacity=".5" stroke-width="4">
    <circle cx="108" cy="108.5" r="100" fill="#0ff" stroke="#0ff"/>
    <circle cx="157.3" cy="209.5" r="100" fill="#ff0" stroke="#ff0"/>
    <circle cx="209.2" cy="109.5" r="100" fill="#f0f" stroke="#f0f"/>
</g>
<rect x="357.2" y="7.53" width="250" height="150" rx="41.429" fill="url(#g)" stroke="#000" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="8 4"/>
<text x="405.11" y="106.51" font-family="Bitstream Vera Sans" font-size="72" font-style="oblique" font-weight="700" fill="#fff" fill-opacity=".5" stroke="#000" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="6 3">SVG</text>
<g transform="matrix(.4033 0 0 .4034 284.7118 53.5686)">
    <path fill="url(#h)" transform="translate(25.72 42.14)" d="M675.82 379.51A182.96 182.96 0 1 0 309.89 379.51 182.96 182.96 0 1 0 675.82 379.51"/>
    <path fill="url(#k)" transform="translate(3 1)" d="M675.82 379.51A182.96 182.96 0 1 0 309.89 379.51 182.96 182.96 0 1 0 675.82 379.51"/>
    <path d="M448.21 203.84C450.36 204.63 453.75 205.95 456.34 207.72 458.94 209.49 460.71 211.6 460.84 214 461.16 219.5 462.73 224.23 456.31 234.22 449.89 244.21 435.16 259.08 402.75 282.44 341.89 326.3 327.7 419.11 324.83 445.46L327.94 453.22C327.94 453.22 336.06 335.44 405.09 285.69 437.69 262.19 452.72 247.17 459.66 236.38 466.59 225.58 465.12 218.64 464.84 213.75 464.61 209.57 461.69 206.56 458.59 204.44 457.31 203.56 455.95 202.87 454.65 202.24L448.21 203.84"/>
    <path d="M509.02 198.03C499.53 209.87 477.92 245.51 465.16 336.75 449.4 449.43 450.71 546.83 450.92 557.84L454.94 558.75C454.94 558.75 452.44 456.6 469.13 337.28 482.75 239.88 506.43 206.86 513.9 198.46 513.9 198.46 509.02 198.03 509.02 198.03"/>
    <path d="M556.69 211.63C547.04 211.81 537.02 214.52 529.97 222.91 520.74 233.89 520.92 245.76 524.5 256.19 528.08 266.61 534.88 275.93 538.97 282.88 541.2 286.67 547.46 295.58 555.44 309.19 563.42 322.8 573.03 340.98 581.72 362.78 599.1 406.39 612.73 464.47 601.94 529.59 601.94 529.59 606.57 526.08 606.57 526.08 616.26 461.74 602.64 404.43 585.44 361.28 576.65 339.24 566.93 320.89 558.88 307.16 550.82 293.42 544.35 284.15 542.41 280.84 538.14 273.59 531.59 264.51 528.28 254.88 524.97 245.24 524.71 235.41 533.03 225.5 541.18 215.8 554.2 214.66 565.56 216.13 576.92 217.59 586.26 221.52 586.26 221.52 586.26 221.52 568.5 212.56 568.5 212.56 567.64 212.42 566.98 212.27 566.09 212.16 563.09 211.77 559.9 211.56 556.69 211.63"/>
    <path d="M458.16 224.97C424.33 226.02 399.2 233.81 381.5 242.41 376.06 245.05 371.36 247.88 367.29 250.52 362.72 255.08 357.49 260.81 350.56 269.41 350.56 269.41 360.3 257.15 383.25 246 406.2 234.85 442.22 224.98 494.53 230.38 599.18 241.17 643.21 296.98 675.72 347 675.72 347 673.38 336.37 673.38 336.37 641.03 288.32 594.99 236.7 494.94 226.38 481.69 225.01 469.43 224.62 458.16 224.97"/>
</g>
</svg>
"""

root = Tk()
img = tksvg.SvgImage(data=svg)
frm = Label(root, image=img)
frm.pack(fill=BOTH)
root.mainloop()
```

Можно, конечно, и в base64 хранить, если хочется.

```
from tkinter import *
import tksvg
import base64

root = Tk()

data="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"
svg = base64.b64decode(data.encode('ascii'))
img = tksvg.SvgImage(data=svg)
frm = Label(root, image=img)
frm.pack(fill=BOTH)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: спасибо, в принципе логично, че сам не допер не знаю, про data у photoimage знал, а вот кодировать не вижу смысла, хочу попробовать создать обертку для создания элементов как на canvas, а точнее писать svg прямо в коде.... например ту же самую button. Напомните в какие элементы tkinter я могу добавить данный svg? label, button, какие еще?